# Chain rule notation

Tags: chain-rule

[image]

For the part $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, do we do $\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}$ first, then evaluate at the point $(x,y)=(x,y(x))?$

[image]

For the part $u_{x}$, do we do $\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}$ first, then evaluate at the point $(x,y)=(x(s),y(s))?$

I was bit confused with different notations. If we are given derivative notation without specify the order of evalution, is there any general rules to follow?

Comment: For the first one, it means that the derivative of $u$ evaluate at some point $\bar{x}$ is
$$
\frac{du}{dx}(\bar{x}) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\bar{x},y(\bar{x})) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\bar{x},y(\bar{x})) \frac{dy}{dx}(\bar{x})
$$
Can you get the secpond rule?

Comment: I should also say that the formula use an abuse of notation that maybe confusing at first.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get the idea. Sometimes I feel confused if there is abuse of notation.

Comment: Yes, notation is very confusing, and it's just one of those things you have to get used to with practice. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270436/568204) is a pretty lengthy answer I wrote a while back regarding various ways of writing down the notation. Perhaps a few other examples might help: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3482215/568204) which deals with expressions encountered in Lagrangian mechanics, but also very relevant here, and also  [partial derivatives in the context of implicit differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3296412/568204).